# Create a dialog home page with jquery mobile

Tags: html, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to create a jquery mobile dialog page but when I load it, it is a classical page and not a dialog even if I included the attribute dialog. Where is the mistake?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dialog Window</title>

    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.4.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.0.1/jquery.mobile-1.0.1.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="dialog">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h1>Login</h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role="content">
            <h2>Hello World!</h2>
        </div>

        <div data-role = "footer">
            <h5>&copy; by Design</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: there is not jquery code...I made a mistake choosing the tags...

Answer (score 3):

Not sure you can do what you're asking. I think jQM Needs a base page to navigate back to once you close the dialog. Would something like this work?

- http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/vsw3r/5/

JS

```
$('#hiddenDialog').trigger('click');
```

HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="home">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Welcome</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <h2>You are here</h2>
    </div>

    <div data-role = "footer">
        <h5>&copy; by Design</h5>
    </div>
    <a href="#loginDialog" id="hiddenDialog" data-rel="dialog" data-transition="pop" style="display:none;">Open dialog</a>
</div>

<div data-role="page" id="loginDialog">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Login</h1>
    </div>

    <div data-role="content">
        <h2>Hello World!</h2>
    </div>

    <div data-role = "footer">
        <h5>&copy; by Design</h5>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I thought to do how you suggest but It is not really what I'm asking but It could the final choice if everything works how could...

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK you have to specify this when showing the page (and not on the page itself).

Try applying `data-rel="dialog"` to the anchor showing the page:
[Dialogs - jQuery Mobile](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0a4.1/docs/pages/docs-dialogs.html)

Comment: but this is home page...there isn't any link that redirect to this page